# Resizing images to fit inside a container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to make a 4 panel screen which would fit the screen of any user who accesses it. The images push everything else out of the div that envolves them. I don't want it to overflow.

My code:

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap h-100">
  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
    <img class=" " src="https://docplayer.org/docs-images/22/1321497/images/61-0.png">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
</div>
```

How I would like it to look:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding css to the images should do the trick

```
max-width: 100%;
```

https://codepen.io/genesy/pen/YzXGXXb it works here.. same code

EDIT: turned it into grid if you want equal image sizes too

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel">
    <img class=" " src="https://docplayer.org/docs-images/22/1321497/images/61-0.png">
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width:
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%:
}
```

Comment: edited answer with a sample for you. i'm not sure what "didn't work" means if you don't explain more

Comment: @GeneSy It doesnt look like his example, it is stretched.

Comment: he said he doesnt want the images to overflow, which doesn't anymore. so if the issue is wanting to have same height accross the images then he should say so @Laif the solution to that is using css grid, or js that defines the height of the panels

Comment: @GeneSy I don't know what to tell you, he drew out an example that shows uniform spacing and it does not look like your code example, therefore it isn't what he is looking for.

Comment: @GeneSy He also drew a literal diagram

Comment: @GeneSy Thanks a lot, man! The second solution with wrapper worked perfectly! Learned about fractional units too (fr) :)

Comment: fr units only work with grid-templates just an fyi :) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid for this:

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
}

img{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="">
    <img class="" src="https://docplayer.org/docs-images/22/1321497/images/61-0.png">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, you actually literally got the image to display exactly like that. Unfortunately I didn't want to use pixels as a measure. The problem is solved now though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Bootstrap4` then don't need to write single line of css code as per your attachment image structure. So follow below html with help of BS4 predefined classes.

Use `vh-100` class for viewport height 100%. 
Use `h-100` class in `row` to inherit parent height.
Use `no-gutters` in `row` class for removing gap.
 
Use `h-50` class for each column height set to 50%.
 
Use `img-fluid mh-100` on image for responsive.

Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid px-0 vh-100">
  <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
    <div class="col-6 h-50">
      <img src="https://docplayer.org/docs-images/22/1321497/images/61-0.png" class="img-fluid mh-100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 h-50">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" class="img-fluid mh-100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 h-50">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" class="img-fluid mh-100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 h-50">
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" class="img-fluid mh-100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```